# How to delete the Duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Table1

```
ID Date

001 23/02/2009
001 24/02/2009
001 24/02/2009
002 25/02/2009
002 25/02/2009
...
```

I want to delete the duplicate rows from the above table.

Expected Output

```
ID Date

001 23/02/2009
001 24/02/2009
002 25/02/2009
...
```

Need Query Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't remember where I got it, but I used to use this SQL to remove duplicates from a table:

```
begin tran deduplicate

select DISTINCT *
into #temp
from mytable

truncate table mytable

insert mytable
select *
from #temp

select * from mytable

drop table #temp
commit tran deduplicate
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do google search you will get plenty of help.

E.g.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/139444

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/01/sql-server-delete-duplicate-records-rows/

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2003/delete-duplicates/